# Throw exceptions without using if - Java

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, throw

Is there a way to throw an exception in your function without using an if statement in Java?
For example, if an integer is smaller than 0, I want to throw an exception, but when checking that specific condition, I don't want to use an if(or switch) statement.

Comment: Why? that's a very contrieved requirement, with no practical reason whatsoever.

Comment: In the same sentence in which you tell you don't want to use an if statement, you imply using one: "when checking that specific condition"... this screams for an if statement, doesn't it?

Comment: You could do something similar and `assert` some variable state.

Comment: you can use ternary operator. or a predicate if you are using java 8+

Comment: If I understand you right, you directly want to throw an exception when an integer gets smaller than 0 without checking with extra code where your integer runs through. That's not really possible. I think the only thing you could do would be an extra Thread where you register all of your Integers and then check them inside this thread with an if statement inside an while(true) loop

Comment: This exercise is for an uni project, where we are not allowed to use neither if statements nor for/while loops. It is meant to teach us how to make use of Java 8 functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign different types of exceptions to a variable using the ternary operator and then throw the exception.

Then you can handle the case where number is smaller than 0 by catching that specific exception and re-throwing it. The other Exception should have an empty catch.

```
int number = 0;

RuntimeException result = number < 0 ? new NumberFormatException() : new RuntimeException();

try {
    throw result;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    throw e;  
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the most approachable solution for what I need!

Comment: @MariaPascu a ternary operator is just a different syntax for an IF, it also checks a boolean condition, the only difference being that it returns a value. Perhaps next time it'll be helpful if you explain in the question _why_ do you need what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* do it, of course, but why?

```
public static void checkNegative(int n) {
    try {
        int[] a = new int[n];
    } catch (NegativeArraySizeException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

The above method will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (or any other exception that you want) if `n < 0`, and will do nothing if `0 <= n < 2^31 - 1`. But surely, somewhere in the code that creates an array there *will* be an `if`, it's implicit.

Also you can use an `assert` to ckeck a condition, which will throw an `AssertionError` if the verified expression is `false` - as long as assertions are enabled:

```
assert n >= 0;
```

And of course, you can throw an exception *without* explicitly verifying a condition, but most of the time you want to check something before throwing an exception.

```
public static void throwForTheHeckOfIt() {
    throw new NumberFormatException();
}
```

How would you know that you need to call the above method, without checking a condition first?

Comment: *"no, you can't throw an arbitrary exception this way"* You can if you catch the `NegativeArraySizeException` and throw the desired arbitrary exception in the `catch` block.

Comment: @Andreas you're right, of course! I updated my answer.

Comment: _"and will do nothing if n >= 0"_ ... unless of course `n` is big enough that the VM can't allocate the array

Comment: @CupawnTae that's a good catch :) . I'm amazed by how people are taking great efforts to perfectly answer such a... nonsensical question!

Answer (score 2):

If I take your question literally, here is an answer. No if statement, and no switch.

```
public class NoIf {

    static void f(int x) throws Exception {
        while (x < 0) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Trying with 1...");
        f(1);
        System.out.println("Trying with -1...");
        f(-1);
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}
```

Quoting Óscar López, from his more elegant answer: But why?

Comment: I like this - it handles bigger numbers than the `new int[n]`, could be adapted to non-ints, and doesn't require assertions to be enabled

Answer (score 1):

You could do a trick with ternary operator however this works like if-statement:

```
public class Task3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        someMethodReturningString(false);
    }

    private static String someMethodReturningString(boolean condition) throws Exception {
        return condition ? "true" : methodThrowingException();
    }

    private static String methodThrowingException() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception("Exception");
    } 
}
```

However it's just a trick. You cannot use throw keyword directly in tenary operator because tenary operator should always return a value. But you can always call methods that return required type in tenary operator.

I don't really know when you would need something like this. I think that if-else construction is best because you often want to throw exceptions "if" something is wrong or some "condition" is met.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't throw an exception from a ternary statement in Java. This won't work

Comment: This works, I have just compiled it. You cannot throw it explicitly like : condition ? "true" : throw new Exception(); Thats why I am using a trick to create a method that returns a value and throws exception. I also wrote about it in my answer.

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant it like:

-Register integers once

-Throw exception when one of these integers turn 0

Wrote this class for that problem:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

class IntegerChecker {
    private ArrayList<AtomicInteger> list = new ArrayList<>();

    IntegerChecker() {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            AtomicBoolean error = new AtomicBoolean(false);
            while (!error.get()) {
                list.forEach(integer -> {
                    if (integer.get() == 0) {
                        error.set(true);
                        throw new RuntimeException();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    void addInt(AtomicInteger i) {
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

To test it use this small program with a JFrame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(5);

    IntegerChecker checker = new IntegerChecker();
    checker.addInt(i);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Click me to throw exception");
    button.addActionListener(e -> i.set(0)); //If you click the button, the integer will turn to 0 which triggers the other class
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

(Could be that I interpreted a bit too much into the post, but I don't see a reason for asking a question like this if you don't mean it the way I thought of)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to throw an exception in your function without using an if statement in Java?

Yes. In general, the `throw` statement does not require an `if` statement.

> For example, if an integer is smaller than 0, I want to throw an exception

Read what you wrote here very carefully. Since you want to throw an exception only when a certain condition is true, then you **must** use an if statement. In general, your code should follow the words that you use to describe it.

> but when checking that specific condition, I don't want to use an if(or switch) statement.

This is not possible. Checking a condition in Java requires an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic simple implementation by Spring framework:

```
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

Assert.isTrue(someCondition,"some condition is not true.");
```

The implementation:

```
public static void isTrue(boolean expression, String message) {
        if (!expression) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
        }
}
```